# Count multiple values in JSON object and print to screen

Tags: javascript, json

I have been searching the web for this, and can only seem to locate the `Object.keys(obj).length` which counts the length of the JSON. I am looking to loop through the JSON and count the values which are the same. In an Array of JSON objects.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 36
    },
    {
        "name": "Billy",
        "age": 18
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 45
    }
]
```

For example, I want to count many `Bob` there are. I would like to then output to a component like so.

`There were 2 Bob`

How can this be achieved? In certain situations I will know that there could only be say 4 values for example. SITE, MOBILE, CTV, VIDEO etc, I forsee collecting them and counting them would be easier than counting a random result.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 36
    },
    {
        "name": "Billy",
        "age": 18
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 45
    }
]

let sums = input.reduce((a, r) => {
  a[r.name] ??= 0
  a[r.name] ++
  return a
}, {})

console.log(sums)
```

Now use `sums` variable to print data in any form you like.